# mysql trigger limit the number of rows inserted for the id column

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I would like my website's users to submit data with my HTML form. However, I want **each user to be limited to 5 submissions total**. To do this, I'm using a MySQL DML trigger to limit my column "um_id" to only five rows per id. But, I know my syntax is wrong and I'm asking anyone here to help correct it so that it could actually work.

Right now I'm testing this in PHPMyAdmin and it will eventually be placed in my PHP file. So um_id will have a value and be concatenated with this SQL Trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ml_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON ml_character;
BEGIN
IF ( SELECT . 'um_id' . COUNT(*) > 5 ) THEN ROLLBACK;
END IF;
```

Comment: Use `having` not really sure what you're querying but something like `SELECT count(*) as the_count where um_id = ? having the_count < 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ml_trigger_bi 
BEFORE INSERT
ON ml_character
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- get count of existing rows with same um_id
   DECLARE li_cnt BIGINT;
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
     FROM ml_character t
    WHERE t.um_id = NEW.um_id
     INTO li_cnt ;
   -- if already five rows, throw error
   IF li_cnt >= 5 THEN
      SIGNAL '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Already five rows in ml_character';
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The value of `um_id` to be checked will come from the row being inserted; we reference that value as `NEW.um_id`.

Comment: Yes this works exactly as I wanted it to! You're amazing! It kept throwing a syntax error #1064, but once I added SQLSTATE right after SIGNAL it actually worked.

Comment: DOH!  I missed the SQLSTATE keyword in the SIGNAL statement. My bad.